# Raspberry pi: Inconsistency detected, assertion failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, updates, raspbian, apt-get, raspberry-pi2

I get the below error when I do: sudo apt-get upgrade

Please help:

Extracting templates from packages: 100%

Preconfiguring packages ...

Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dynamic-link.h: 190: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[20]->d_un.d_val == 17 || info[20]->d_un.d_val == 7' failed!

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)

Comment: It's better to ask this question over at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay I will post it there also, but would like to see if someone reaches this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably file system was corrupted. I had to reinstall the OS :(